# Is RSA-signing zero knowledge?

Tags: rsa, signature, zero-knowledge-proofs

Is RSA-signing a given challenge $x$ a *zero-knowledge proof* of holding the RSA private key, for the modern definition of *zero-knowledge proof* (which I don't know!)

Assume public and genuine RSA public key $(n,e)$, secret RSA private key $(n,e,d,p,q\ldots)$ with distinct secret primes $p$ and $q$, that the factorization of $n$ can't be found from the public key or from access to a textbook RSA signature oracle, and that the RSA assumption holds.

If necessary, distinguish between

- textbook RSA signature $x\mapsto x^d\bmod n$
- RSA signature with deterministic padding, e.g. [RSA-FDH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_Domain_Hash), or [RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5](https://pkcs1.grieu.fr#%5B%7B%22num%22:90,%22gen%22:0%7D,%7B%22name%22:%22XYZ%22%7D,118,721,null%5D)
- RSA signature with random padding, e.g. [RSASSA-PSS](https://pkcs1.grieu.fr#%5B%7B%22num%22:78,%22gen%22:0%7D,%7B%22name%22:%22XYZ%22%7D,118,314,null%5D)

Motivation is [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/100454/555), and specifically [this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/100459/555).

Update: I'm reading the answers to a [similar question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/35177/555) (on signature in general) as *no*. But I'd like an answer based on a definition of *zero-knowledge proof*.

Comment: This question is still bugging me as well. On the other hand, this answer (https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/35185/58690) seems to show that such a protocol isn't necessarily ZK? Taking into account that ZKP is supposed to reveal nothing else, I wonder if for RSA (e.g.: FDH), the singer is additionally revealing $e'th$ roots?

Comment: It's relatively easy to see that textbook RSA signatures would not lead to a ZK protocol. A simulator would have to be able to invert the RSA TDP on a significant fraction of the domain, which would simply break the RSA assumption. (It's probably also no a proof of knowledge of anything, at least I don't see how the extractor should work.) But that's not a secure signature scheme, so that seems kind of irrelevant. It *is* HVZK I think. Just compute the transcript backwards.

Comment: Obviously, if a ZKP is supposed to reveal nothing other than the truth of the assertion, signing a challenge message is not ZK - after all, in addition to the statement "the prover knows the private key", the challenger also learns "what is a valid signature for message $x$?"

Comment: My comment on FDH RSA was actually incorrect. We can't reprogram at that point in a deterministic signature scheme. For a randomized version of FDH it would work.

Comment: @poncho that's not the definition of ZK though. That's an intuitive description of what it's supposed to achieve and it often leads people astray.

Comment: @Maeher, doesn't the requirement that there exists a simulator that can simulate the transcript distribution imply that the verifier learns nothing else than the true value of what is claimed?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, we do not not know that any of the signature schemes is proof of holding the RSA secret key $d$. They would be proof of possession of an RSA decryption oracle/method corresponding to the exponent $e$, but we don't know if this necessarily implies knowledge of $d$. This is related to the unanswered question as to whether the [RSA problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_problem) is as hard as factoring. If we know $d$, we could factor the modulus and so if access to a decryption oracle implies knowledge of $d$ then the RSA problem is equivalent to factoring.

However, if someone can produce arbitrary text book RSA signatures for any exponent $e$ rather than just a fixed one, then this would imply knowledge of $d$ because this "generic" RSA problem is known to be equivalent to factoring (see Aggarwal and Maurer [Breaking RSA Generically is Equivalent to Factoring](https://eprint.iacr.org/2008/260.pdf)).

Producing signatures for uniform random inputs in textbook RSA is zero-knowledge because the transcripts can be simulated simply by choosing a uniform random output and raising to the power $e$. More structured outputs cannot easily be simulated and a supplied challenge would need to be randomly blinded to guarantee zero-knowledge.

Comment: [Is it proven that breaking RSA is equivalent to factoring as of 2021?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/89894/18298)